# Can not put 2 digits on NgModel Ionic. Pointer disappear

Tags: ionic-framework, input, ionic2, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to bind an ion-input from an array, but when I want to change the value on the screen, the input disappear. I mean, if I put the pointer into the text-area, the pointer is gone and I have to put again.

But, if I remove the [(ngModel)] the pointer is never gone.

Here I let the code of the ion-input.

```
    <ion-col *ngFor="let x of totalExercices[ex].maquina.repeticions; let ma = index;">

        <ion-input type="number"
                  [(ngModel)]="totalExercices[ex].maquina.repeticions[ma]"
                  style="background-color:#f4f4f4;">
        </ion-input>

    </ion-col>
```

On the following images, if we fix on the element 20. If I want to delete the number, when the 0 is gone, the pointer is gone too.

[trying to delete the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9wZD.png)

And looks like this:
[Deleted the 0, but I have to put again the pointer there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrqWx.png)

As I said, I guess that the problem is the ngModel.

Pherhaps there are some other ways to change the value of that input withous the ngModel?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, After searching the issue, I've finded the solution. If we bind a NgModel using an array, it load every time, so the list is reloaded every time we do some change. 
The solution is the **track by** See the solution on the following link:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/2-way-data-binding-to-an-array-element-in-an-ngfor-ionic-2-rc1/67977/2